# RelativeLayout shrinking bottom item

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a list of items in a relative layout, and for some reason the bottom item gets shrunk. It's layout xml is identical to the other ones. I'm including a link to the picture that shows the code and the layout image, since I don't have enough rep to post an image.

[Weird Layout Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky2NE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you're trying to achieve here, plus I can't see very well on the screenshot, but that may well be because you set `adjustViewBounds`.
The last `View` has very little space in height, and since `adjustViewBounds` is set its width is reduced by the same ratio as its height.

How to solve it will depend on what you want to do UI-wise, but this may be *closer to* what you're looking for:

```
<ImageView
    android:id=...
    android:src=...
    android:below=...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Achieving your desired visual result through a single 9-patch may be a lot better though.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a seamless notebook page that I can infinitely extend. So those are all iterations of a single image of a few lines of notebook paper. 

If I take away the asjustViewBounds, they start having a large margin around the image which destroys the effect. 

The strange thing about this is that all the copies of the image are described identically, but only the last one is shrunk.

Comment: Because only the last one has too little height. If you're aiming at a layout that "infinitely extend", you'll have to do it programmatically, not by copy pasting several identical views in xml. 2 things: 1. I guess the margins are because you're using `wrapContent`, if you want them to extend use `matchParent` 2. if your layout can grow "infinitely", you'll need to put it into a `ScrollView` to extend its viewport. (And then you can leave `adjustViewBounds` if you want to protect the image ratio)

Comment: I'm planning on extending it programmatically, this is just the initial page. I can't put it in a ScrollView, because it only takes one child.

Comment: That one child usually is a (linear) layout, that's not a problem. As for your current layout, try what I put in my answer or else go with a nine-patch or even better draw your canvas programmatically.

Comment: Well, the problem here is that I've been avoiding ScrollView because I need to handle the touch activities myself. It looks like I'll need to override the scrolling with onInterceptTouchEvent and deal with it there. 

I still think the layout changing only the bottom element is really inconsistent and frustrating.

Comment: Well I think you're approaching it the wrong way. Keep in mind that your app may run on a variety of devices, with very different screen sizes and dpi and resolutions, so with the kind of layout you're trying to implement now, it may look fine on a given devices but will be weird on another. Don't know the kind of UI interactions you're planning, but unless it's something really "fancy" like say a video game, I would advise to stay as close as possible to the Android default resources (e.g. avoid overriding the scrolling procedure for example). But we're drifting from the original question.

Comment: The upshot is that I need a layout that adds art to the backround when it's dragged, and that I can add other layouts to. 

Right now, I'm to the point where I've extended RelativeLayout, and created the initial layout programmatically, but when I add more imageviews to in on drag, it does not resize. 

I understand what you're saying about hewing to default conventions as much as possible, but none of them seem to be able to provide this.

Comment: Why not use a `ListView` ? Otherwise for your original issue did you try the code I put in my answer ?